# Hide and show elements using `location.hash` value

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 simple div elements.I need to hide and show it based on url.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='myController'>
  <div ng-show="addnotes" class="block"> 
   paragraph 1
  </div>

  <div ng-show="!addnotes" class="block">
  paragraph 2
  </div>

  <button ng-click='clickme()'>
  Add Notes
  </button>
</div>
```

on page load `paragraph 2` div element will be displayed.when I click on `Add notes` button,I need to add `location.hash` value as `addnotes`.Once I added this condition should be changed to `$scope.addnotes=true;` so div elements will be toggled.

I have done this and its working fine.
But my problem is , its working only if i refresh the page after adding hash value.

`I need to do this without refreshing the page`.How can I do it? Any help thanks!!

sample fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/70Luf7hu/59/

Answer (score 1):

It's should work with function call expression, and you should not use **location** object driectly, use **$location** service istead (as recommended in AngularJs document [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#when-should-i-use-location-))

Js :

```
app.controller('myController',function($scope,$location){
    $scope.addnotes=false;
  $scope.clickme = function(){
  $location.hash('addnotes')
  }
  $scope.addnotes = function(){
   return $location.hash()=='addnotes';
  //location.reload();
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <div ng-show="addnotes()" class="block"> 
   paragraph 1
  </div>

  <div ng-show="!addnotes()" class="block">
  paragraph 2
  </div>

  <button ng-click='clickme()'>
  Add Notes
  </button>
```

[image: demo image]